# Regular expression for split in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split all commas and spaces for example:

```
String[] text = "tag1, tag2 tag3,     tag4";
```

The excpected result is:

```
result[0] = "tag1"
result[1] = "tag2"
result[2] = "tag3"
result[3] = "tag4"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I get this error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Depends on how you used it.

Comment: what do u mean?
res = test.split("\s*,\s*");

Comment: I guess you need to escape the backslashes in the string, try `res = test.split("\\s*,\\s*")`.

Comment: But it is not including the space between tag2 tag3...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103378/discussion-between-user11001-and-tushar).

Comment: Your problem is you have 2 usages for spaces - 1) delimiter 2) padding. It would take 2 passes to split this and then join the 2 resulting arrays after trimming.

Comment: Split by `[ ,]+` or `[\s,]+`, e.g.: `res = test.split("[\\s,]+");`.  @dlcole, this is something new for you :)

Comment: Hey..educate me. We can all learn something new everyday. That's why I'm here. @Nishi can you incorporate your regex into his code and provide a working example showing the correct results?

Comment: @Nishi - You were are right..[\\s,]+ works. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Update - With the regular expression Nishi suggested, you can do this on a simpler fashion:

```
String text = "tag1, tag2 tag3,     tag4";
String[] result = text.split("[\\s,]+");
for (String s : result) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Results in:

```
[tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]
```

Comment: Can you use Groovy instead of Java? Then you could use a spread operator and knock this out in one line.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] result = text.split(",[ ]*");
```

Comment: This one helps by removing the padding, but still ends up with 'tag2 tag3' combined. Nice regex though.